# I can't find my agent class from the CLASSPATH in the JADE Main Container GUI

Tags: java, agents-jade

I can start the main container from the command line.
I have created my Agent class  inside a package jade/tools/server
I have followed the [Hello World Agent Example](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer2.html) to have a simple and behavioral agent.
I have also seen the sample agents in the jade source files. 
I don't under stand while my agent is not listed among the others; which are pre-created in the jade source files and examples.

[Start New Agent Dialog of the Remote Agent Management GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghGxK.png)

Please some help is needed here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe JADE does not find the class. Can you provide an example of your command line or a description of your setup. From where you're starting JADE (e.g. from eclipse)? Or did you compile your code to a jar file and trying to start Java with the -classpath option?

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things